# vim-latex problem on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I'm using vim with cygwin on Windows XP. I have Miktex install and I can compile files using Texmaker for example.

However, I'd like to use vim with the vim-latex suite. When I type

```
:echo Tex_CompileRule_dvi
```

It just gives me an error. However when I type

```
:!latex -interaction=nonstopmode %
```

I'm able to compile it. So it seems that vim doesn't recognise that I have vim-latex installed on my machine. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933/how-do-i-list-loaded-plugins-in-vim), could you run `:scriptnames` and check that `latex-suite` lines appear, showing that the plugin has been correctly installed ? In my case, with a working plugin, I get for instance the line `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Vincent. It appears that the plugin is not installed correctly. I shall have a look at what's wrong.

Comment: I have figured out the problem. I copied all the files to ~/vimfiles as described in the installation instructions. However, when I made this ~/.vim then it started working. So I guess, if you're using vim-latex suite on cygwin then you have to have .vim directory rather than vimfiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OPs comment converted to an answer]

I have figured out the problem. I copied all the files to `~/vimfiles` as described in the installation instructions. However, when I made this `~/.vim` then it started working. So I guess, if you're using `vim-latex` suite on Cygwin then you have to have `.vim` directory rather than `vimfiles`.